# Excepción al utilizar la clase Scanner de Java en NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-util-scanner

Estaba probando en NetBeans la función de la clase `Scanner`, pero por algún motivo me salta un error y no me deja ingresar datos desde la consola.

Aquí está el código:

```
package LeerDatos;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nro;
        System.out.print("Ingrese un numero: ");
        nro = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Su numero es: "+nro);
    }
    
}
```

Al ejecutarlo el error que me aparece es éste:

```
> Task :run FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at LeerDatos.Main.main(Main.java:12)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

He probado utilizando un `if` como leí en otra pregunta:

```
        if(entrada.hasNextInt() )
            nro = entrada.nextInt();
```

Así el programa finaliza bien, pero claro, no me deja ingresar los datos.

(Edit) Al final no supe por qué NetBeans me daba ese error, pero con Eclipse funciona bien todo. ¡Gracias por sus comentarios!

Comment: Bienvenido, que versión de net beans estás usando ?

Comment: La versión 12.0, creo que es la última. Y con el JDK 11

Comment: No veo que pudieras tener problemas con el código que agregas dentro de main() solo veo que usas el JDK 11

Comment: Trataré de utilizar otro entorno, espero sea ese el problema.

Comment: realicé el mismo ejercicio con tu versión de netbeans y JDK 11. No deberías tener problema. Revisa que no esten causando conflicto otras versiones de JDK. Revisa que netbeans este compilando con la versión que le especificaste en su instalación, para tu caso la versión 11 y que esta apunte a JDK. public static void main(String[] args) { try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) { System.out.println("Ingresa un numero: "); int name = input.nextInt(); System.out.println("El numero es: " + name); } } > Ingresa un numero: 30 El numero es: 30 Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que NetBeans ejecuta de manera no interactiva tu aplicación, por lo que la entrada estándar está vacía.

---

**Edición:**

Buscando en Internet he encontrado dos referencias a tu problema en el seguimiento de errores de NetBeans:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3073

> When trying to build a console application with Gradle in Netbeans, it can't get the user input.

En castellano:

> Al intentar crear una aplicación de consola en Netbeans usando Gradle, no se puede obtener la entrada del usuario.

Este error afecta únicamente a plataformas Windows y parece que está arreglado en NetBeans 11.2, por lo que si usas la versión 12 es probable que se trate de una regresión.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4099

En este caso solucionan el problema agregando la siguiente línea en el archivo `build.gradle`:

```
run.standardInput = System.in
```

De cualquier manera, si ejecutas tu aplicación desde símbolo del sistema debería funcionarte perfectamente como te han indicado en los comentarios en multitud de ocasiones.

---

Sea un error el origen del problema o que tu aplicación esté siendo usada normalmente y alguien envíe, por ejemplo, mediante una tubería (`|`) un valor vacío, cuando tu código encuentra la entrada sin datos se genera la excepción que está documentada en [`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()):

> Throws: `NoSuchElementException` - if input is exhausted

En castellano:

> Lanza: `NoSuchElementException` - si la entrada se ha agotado

Como tu aplicación no hace las comprobaciones mínimas necesarias para que no se genere una excepción (ni tampoco la capturas) deberías, como mínimo, comprobar si existe un entero por leer con [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) antes de extraerlo mediante [`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()):

> `Scanner.hasNextInt()` returns `true` if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the `nextInt()` method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

En castellano:

> `Scanner.hasNextInt()` devuelve `true` si el siguiente token en la entrada del escáner se puede interpretar como un valor `int` en la base predeterminada usando el método `nextInt()`. El escáner no avanza más allá de ninguna entrada.

Es decir, que antes de leer los datos debes comprobar si está ahí disponibles:

```
package LeerDatos;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nro;
        System.out.print("Ingrese un numero: ");
        if (entrada.hasNextInt()) {
            nro = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Su número es: " + nro);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No había ningún número que leer.");
        }
    }
}
```

Con este código también evitas la excepción `InputMismatchException` que se produce si el dato introducido no es un entero (por ejemplo, si escribes la palabra `hola` en vez de un número).